# Sharing Video Card Serial Number

Tags: video, graphics-card, amd-radeon

Would anyone be able to inform me whether serial numbers are to be kept private? I have a video card that I am selling on eBay and I am getting a request for the serial number by an eBay member so that he can check the warranty status. Can I share this number?

Thanks,
-D

Comment: There's no real personally identifiable information in a serial number, but it is conceivable that he could be after the number in order to create an RMA for a card he has lying around that is out of warranty. It depends how trustworthy you think he is. Personally I'd find out how to check the warranty status myself and share a screenshot of the website with any information blurred out.

Comment: The warranty would normally be through wherever you bought the card from at any rate as only they would know exactly when you bought the card. Most manufacturers would refer you to your supplier for support or repair claims.